# FileExist not working vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I really can not understand why the exception is triggered. 
I created this code that performs some checks for the correctness of the license. 
The function isittrial occurs if the trial software is creating a hidden file, this file is then checked with File.exist. 
The problem is the following:

the file is created by isittrial but for some strange reason you enable the exception of file.exist, what can I do to fix it?

I really can not understand why it does not work.

```
    isittrial() 'this function make the file to check

    Dim percorsoCompleto As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\Software\cc.txt"

    Try
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(directory) Then
            Dim fileReader As String
            Dim dire As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\Software\cc.txt"
            fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(directory,
               System.Text.Encoding.UTF32)

            Dim check = DeCryptIt(fileReader, "aspanet")
            Dim datadecripted As String = DeCryptIt(Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\cc", "end", ""), "aspanet")

            If Date.Now < check And check <> datadecripted Then

                MsgBox("License not valid", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Attention!")
                DeActivate()
                ForceActivation()
            Else
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox("License not valid", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Attention!")
            DeActivate()
            ForceActivation()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("License not valid", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Attention!")
        'DeActivate()
        'ForceActivation()
    End Try
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are testing a file and not a directory? The two error messages are identical so you don't really know if the error is an exception or just a call that tells you that you cannot ask the existence of a file passing a directory name

Comment: What is the value of "`directory`"?

Comment: I check if the text file exists.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
 If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(directory) Then
```

seems to test for the existence of a file passing the name of a directory (or an empty string or whatever, we can see how this variable is initialized). In every case the result will be false.

Then your code jumps to an else block with the same error message of the exception fooling your perception of the error.

Try instead

```
Dim percorsoCompleto As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) 
percorsoCompleto = Path.Combine(percorsoCompleto, "Software", "cc.txt")
Try
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(percorsoCompleto) Then
        Dim fileReader As String
        fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(percorsoCompleto,
                                 System.Text.Encoding.UTF32)
        .....
```

Notice that I have removed the path concatenation with a more fail safe call to [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: so... what's the problem? I think that the code catch another exception infact i get this: NullReferenceException in this code

Comment: But this is probably another question. It seems that the error message is now different so, the previous error has been solved. Try to comment out the Try/Catch and see on which line you get the exception

Comment: where I can see the line number? The error I get from the application and not when I debug.

Comment: Let the program crash without the Try/Catch then look at the details window and you should be able to trace back to the point in your code that raises the exception. I would bet Registry.GetValue is not returning anything

Comment: i fix it, were the name of general exception that was wrong.